# Vim line breaks & Markdown conflict

Tags: vim, markdown

I'm writing Markdown with Vim. Let's say my file contains this:

```
La Cigale, ayant chanté tout l'été,  
Se trouva fort dépourvue  
Quand la bise fut venue.

_Jean de la Fontaine_
```

I know that if I want to add line breaks I have to add two spaces at the end of said line (this is what I did here). But when reformatted by Vim this is transformed as:

```
La Cigale, ayant chanté tout l'été,  Se trouva fort dépourvue  Quand la bise
fut venue.  

_Jean de la Fontaine_
```

My problem is that when working with text I include `a` in my `formatoptions` and I'm accidentally reformatting paragraphs and losing all my lines breaks a lot of time. I know that when "compiled" this will still produce the output that I want. But I'd like my file to look as readable as possible. Is there a way to do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Adding `w` to my `formatoptions` fixed it.

```
w   Trailing white space indicates a paragraph continues in the next line.
    A line that ends in a non-white character ends a paragraph.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override `formatoptions` for Markdown files. Create a `~/.vim/ftplugin/mkd.vim` and put this in it:

```
setlocal formatoptions-=a
```

You can put whatever commands you want in this file, and they'll get executed when you edit a Markdown file. Using `setlocal` makes the option affect only the current buffer, and putting it in a `ftplugin` file makes it apply whenever the matching filetype is encountered.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but actually I like/need `a` in my `formatoptions`. If I were working only on short lines like in my example I could accept your answer, but I might also be working on paragraphs of long sentences with line breaks in it. In such cases every time I make and edit or `gqap` all my line breaks are lost. It seems to me like Vim is unable to tell which breaks were meant (even when I differentiate them by inserting two spaces the line before).